# SQL insert syntax, database not updating

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010, insert

EDIT

i changed the code so i am using:[" + Time1 + "] instead of the parameter. This works for the first time, but when the time increases by 0.5, it stays false. The for loop is working as i tried a  MessageBox.Show("" + Time1 + ""); inside the for loop.

```
for (double Time = time_began_5; Time < time_finished_5; Time = Time + 0.5)
        {
            string Time1 = Time.ToString("0.00");


            try
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=AllensCroft;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;");

                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Slots ([Date],[RoomID],[" + Time1 + "]) Values (@date,@room,1)", cn);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("room", rooms_combo.SelectedValue);


                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                try
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the SQL error?

Comment: First of all, is the loop even executing?  P.S. It's generally considered bad practice to use a Double as an indexer variable in a for loop!

Comment: is @time your column name if not then why did you use there?

Comment: Time is a column and a variable and i wanted it to be true, is that possible

Comment: @JackPettinger It is just the database not updating

Comment: the loop is executing because i tried console.writeline Time within the loop and it worked

Comment: I suggest you step through your code and see what error is caught in your `try catch`. I suspect your are trying to insert into a column that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have a `@` before your 3rd column (time).
2. When you add a parameter you need to add the `@`.
3. On your insert statement you are trying to insert true as a boolean into the `time` column.

```cs
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Slots (Date,RoomID,time) " + "Values (@date,@room,@time)", cn);

Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room", rooms_combo.SelectedValue);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", Time);
```

**EDIT** After comments. Try this:

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Slots (Date,RoomID,[" + Time1 + "]) " + "Values (@date,@room,@time)", cn);

Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room", rooms_combo.SelectedValue);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", true);
```

Comment: Time is a column and it is boolean and i wanted it to be true, is that possible, e.g. the column 8.5, i wanted that to be true

Comment: If you want to insert `true` into the time column, then the SQL datatype needs to be a `bit`. Is this is the case then there is no need to the `@time` parameter, what is it for?

Comment: it is just to reference the time column, e.g.8.50, 8.00

Comment: Are you saying you have different columns for different times? ie, a column for 8.00, 8.15, 8.30 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't include a variable in your column list, I presume you wanted that @Time to be in the value list about where that true is.

EDIT: To inject the time as a column name, do some C# string manipulation:

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Slots (Date, RoomID, [" + time + "]) Values (@date, @room, 1)", cn);
```

EDIT again: true is not a T-SQL keyword, T-SQL bit columns have values 1 or 0

Now you don't want to add time as a parameter to the query.

Comment: Time is a column and a variable and i wanted it to be true, is that possible, e.g. the column 8.5, i wanted that to be true

Comment: @Hamoudy Answer updated with what I think you you're asking for

Comment: i thied this, but same problem  SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Slots (Date,RoomID,8.00) Values (@date,@room,true)", cn);

Comment: @Hamoudy The square brackets I included are vital, 8.00 requires escaping to be used as a column name. Also, I just updated the answer to reflect that you don't use `true` as a value in SQL Server, you use 1.

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do with those time columns isn't really in line with what relational database theory suggests. You're breaking the third normal form because your time columns aren't independent.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26121/discussion-between-mattw-and-hamoudy)

Answer (score 0):

You're listing a variable as a column name (@time)

**EDIT**
Right here:

`INSERT INTO Slots (Date, RoomID,` **--->>>** @time **<<<--- DANGER WILL ROBINSON, DANGER**

To fix it, you need to either change it to a column name from your table, or else get rid of it.

So something like this, for example:

`INSERT INTO Slots (Date, RoomID, time)`